# std::map trick for comparing unrepresentable numbers?

Tags: c++, math, hash, stl, dictionary

I would like to have a user-defined key in a C++ `std::map`. The key is a binary representation of an integer set with maximum value `2^V` so I can't represent all `2^V` possible values. I do so by means of an efficient binary set representation, i.e., an array of `uint64_t`.

Now the problem is that to put this user-defined bitset as key in a `std::map`, I need to define a valid comparison between bitset values but if I have a maximum size of, say, `V=1000`, then I cannot get a number I can compare, let alone aggregating them all i.e., `2^1000` is not representable.

Therefore my question is, suppose I have two different sets (by setting the right bits in my bitset representation) and I cannot represent the final number because it will overflow:

```
id_1 = 2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^V

id_2 = 2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^V
```

Is there a suitable transformation that would lead to a value I can compare? I need to be able to say `id_1 < id_2` so I would like to transform a sum of exponentials to a value that is representable BUT maintaining the invariant of the "less than".  I was thinking along the lines of e.g. applying a log transformation in a clever way to preserve "less than".

Here is an example:

```
set_1 = {2,3,4}; set_2 = {8}

id(set_1) = 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 = 28; id(set_2) = 2^8 = 256

id(set_1) < id(set_2)
```

Perfect! How about a general set that can have `{1,...,V}`, and thus `2^V` possible subsets?

Comment: Why don't you compare the values themselves? You will always suffer from the mapping of your `id`s to the limited integers being not bijective.

Comment: Exactly. Whenever you try to convert from one set to a smaller one, you run into the chance of conflicts and incorrect comparison. A bit by bit comparison seems like the way to go here.

Comment: bit by bit comparison doesn't solve the problem. Suppose you have an array of int64_t and the further you go the exponent gets e.g. 2^5000 how can you compare without aggregating? I simply don't see how.

Comment: "how can you compare without aggregating" - lexicographically?

Comment: Don't use `uint64_t` unless your application **absolutely** requires **exactly** 64 bits. In general, use `uint_least64_t`, since `uint64_t` is not required to exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I do so by means of an efficient binary set representation, i.e., an array of uint64_t.

Supposing that this array is accessed via a data member `ra` of the key type `Key`, and both arrays are of length `N`, then you want a comparator something like this:

```
bool operator<(const Key &lhs, const Key &rhs) {
    return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.ra, &lhs.ra[N], rhs.ra, &rhs.ra[N]);
}
```

This implicitly considers the array to be big-endian, i.e. the first `uint64_t` is the most significant. If you don't like that, that's fair enough, since you might already have in mind some relative significance for whatever order you've stored your `V` bits into your array. There's no great mystery to `lexicographical_compare`, so just look at [an example implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare#Possible_implementation) and modify as required.

This is called "lexicographical order". Other than the facts that I've used `uint64_t` instead of `char` and both arrays are the same length, it is how strings are compared[*] -- in fact the use of `uint64_t` isn't important, you could just use `std::memcmp` in your comparator instead of comparing 64-bit chunks. `operator<` for strings doesn't work by converting the whole string to an integer, and neither should your comparator.

[*] until you bring locale-specific collation rules into play.

Comment: You can also use `std::lexicographical_compare`, which does exactly this.

Comment: @interjay: well I never, that's been there all along. OK.

Comment: Thank you! I actually thought of lexicographical ordering but using a string, then I figured it would be a waste to have such possibly very long strings ... I didnt know I could do lexicographical ordering on the uint64_t arrays directly. Thanks!

Comment: @Giovanni: yep, lexicographical order applies in principle to any sequences (not necessarily the same length) of values taken from any type that itself is ordered. `lexicographical_compare` implements that in C++.